# Quality of answers for duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I've seen this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186841/how-to-write-%E2%89%99-in-latex) closed as a duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103408/symbol-for-corresponds-to-equals-sign-with-hat).

It's actually a duplicate, but... Answers in the new question are much way better, than a duplicate. So, my reason was, why to close as a duplicate of question, that has some worse answers, than already given?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general StackOverflow model is that multiple questions asking the same thing should be combined to one place where the answers can be found. This can get complicated when there are two or more questions with some good answers. Possible approaches include:

- Duplicating the newer question to the older one (works best if this is spotted early and answers thus accumulate on the older question)
- 'Reverse' duping the older question to the newer one
- Merging the questions (moves answers from one to another): best when both questions have good answers. This can only be done after duping.

Which route is best depends on the quality of the question (which is easier to read/find) and the answers.

In the case in point, the older question is probably better but the newer answers are perhaps stronger, so merging might be the best plan.

Comment: And how the questions can be merged? I've found only some old [news](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/), but haven't found any *merged* questions. Is that a moderator only? And what is being done to the users reputation, who asked new questions after merge? His question lead to a new answers, loosing his reputation isn't an option. Maybe I missed some points...

Comment: @m0nhawk Merging is mod-only and we've been relatively cautious about it (it's not that easy to find clear-cut cases). Users don't get any more rep for questions after a merge, but the argument of course is that if a dupe was appropriate then there was an older _question_ which was clear and on the same topic. (I do see that they've drawn attention to the issue and therefore led to more/better  answers.)